# Any alternative for PicPick on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, screen-capture

I need simple tool with two feathures, accessible by hotkeys:

1. Color picker;
2. Tool like "Screen Crosshair" in PicPick, for simple get size of any region of screen.

I can't find any alternative. Mac OS really hasn't it?
I found only color pickers, but no "crosshair" app.
xScope has a little similar functions, but it's unusable in both cases.
Thanks!

Comment: This maybe of assistance http://alternativeto.net/software/picpick/?platform=mac

Comment: I already looked this page. There are screenshot tools, but no app with tool like "Screen Crosshair", and no color pickers.

Comment: Hopefully there will be an App that suits your needs.

Comment: This question is probably off-topic. It is a better fit for [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: there isn't, they all suck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using [FreeRuler](http://www.pascal.com/software/freeruler/) for on-screen measurements, and [DigitalColor Meter](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/apple-in-the-enterprise/discover-the-digitalcolor-meter-tool-on-your-mac/) for color inspection. DigitalColor Meter (DCM) is bundled with Mac OS X.

Comment: DigitalColor Meter looks good, thanks. But no HEX colors? 
Screen Ruler has usability problems, like xScope. It requires many actions to get block size. And it hasn't fullscreen cross-lines to take bounds of block easily.

Comment: In DigitalColor Meter, choose View > Display Values > As Hexadecimal.

Comment: You might also consider 'command + shift + 4', which will let you drag out an area while displaying live dimensions. Tap escape to keep the Mac from actually taking the screenshot.

Comment: Thanks! I think command + shift + 4 is the best for me. Pressing escape anytime is little crappy, but it's faster solution. May be I made own app later...

Answer (score 0):

I find PixelStick works really well. It's on the app store or you can get a free trial from: http://plumamazing.com/mac/pixelstick. It does angles, regions lengths and hex colours.

Comment: Looks interesting, but it require many actions to get size too. Sorry, I can't like your answer for now, but thanks for it.